# Webpack error when loading dependencies of a dependency

Tags: webpack, package.json

Files:

package.json

```
{
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --display-error-details --config ./webpack-config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "simple-oauth2": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

webpack-config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

index.js

```
var simpleOauth2 = require('simple-oauth2');
```

When I run `npm start`, I get:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/joi/lib/string.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/node_modules/joi/lib'
resolve 'net' in '/home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/node_modules/joi/lib'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/node_modules/joi/package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/node_modules/joi/package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    resolve as module
      /home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/node_modules/joi/lib/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/node_modules/joi/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/node_modules/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/someone/github/nickname/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/someone/github/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/someone/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/node_modules
        using description file: /home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: /home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/net)
            as directory
              /home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/node_modules/net doesn't exist
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/node_modules/net doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/node_modules/net.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/node_modules/net.json doesn't exist
[/home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/node_modules/joi/lib/node_modules]
[/home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/node_modules/joi/node_modules]
[/home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/node_modules/node_modules]
[/home/someone/github/nickname/node_modules]
[/home/someone/github/node_modules]
[/home/someone/node_modules]
[/home/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
[/home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/node_modules/net]
[/home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/node_modules/net]
[/home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/node_modules/net.js]
[/home/someone/github/nickname/webpack-demo/node_modules/net.json]
 @ ./node_modules/joi/lib/string.js 5:12-26
 @ ./node_modules/joi/lib/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/simple-oauth2/index.js
 @ ./src/index.js
```

I've read about resolving modules in webpack, I've tried several webpack version.
If instead of loading `simple-oauth2` I load `lodash` it works. `lodash` as no dependencies, so my best guess is that my current webpack configuration cannot handle dependencies of `simple-oauth2`.

I'll appreciate some help on understanding where to start to solve this :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, I'm super naive. This `simple-oauth2` library is for node.js only and it cannot run as it is in a browser.

This is where http://browserify.org/ comes in, example here: http://www.bradoncode.com/tutorials/browserify-tutorial-node-js/

Some node.js libraries have a browser version already available as a package like `request`:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/request
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-request